# Execute shell command with `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`

Tags: java, coldfusion, railo

I wrote the following little script in CFML that executes a shell command, my problem is with the output, as long as the output is a single line is ok, if is multi-line I get only the first line, I tried to do a while loop on the script (commented on the code) but doesn't work and Java throws a memory error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. What can I do?

```
<cfscript>
  str = ":>exec uname";
  exec_init=str.split(":>exec ");
  exec=exec_init[2].split(" ");
  p = createObject("java","java.lang.ProcessBuilder").init(exec).start();
  i = createObject("java","java.io.InputStreamReader").init(p.getInputStream());
  br = createObject("java","java.io.BufferedReader").init(i);
  line=br.readLine();
  //while (isDefined("line")) {
   //writeoutput(line);
  //}
  br.close();
  i.close();
</cfscript>

<cfdump var="#line#">
```

Output:

`Linux`

If I issue a command like

`ls`

with multi-line output I get e.g.

`README.TXT`

instead:

`README.TXT  VERSION.txt  _-Railo-Getting-Started-_.html  bin  etc  jre  lib  license-eplv10-aslv20.html  modules  notice.html  resources  start  start.d  start.ini  start.jar  stop  webapps`

Comment: What's "a memory error"? Add the real error that you get and where you get it exactly. Right now your code is only reading one line so logically, it will only receive one line.

Comment: I'm getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I know my code is reading only one line, any idea how to read them all?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use cfexecute?  I'm aware of several features cfexecute doesn't provide to you (working directory, env variables, and results as an input stream) but your code sample doesn't seem to show a need for any of those.  If you're just going to use the entire output string once it's collected, it would be easier just to run cfexecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem, I needed to add again `line = br.readLine();` in my loop. Working code:

```
<cfscript>
  str = ":>exec ls -al";
  exec_init=str.split(":>exec ");
  exec=exec_init[2].split(" ");
  p = createObject("java","java.lang.ProcessBuilder").init(exec).start();
  i = createObject("java","java.io.InputStreamReader").init(p.getInputStream());
  br = createObject("java","java.io.BufferedReader").init(i);
  line = br.readLine();
  while (isDefined("line")) {
   writeoutput(line);
   line = br.readLine();
  }
  br.close();
  i.close();
</cfscript>
```

Comment: (Edit) Do not forget to process the error stream as well the output. If desired, you can redirect the error stream to standard output using [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks about the tip! Any idea how?

Comment: Either read the `getErrorStream()` separately, just like with p.getInputStream() OR use `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)` so errors are written to the standard stream. For the latter you have to separate the `init()` and `start()` calls into two lines so you can access the ProcessBuilder object.  Also, use if you want to wait for the process to finish, use `p.waitFor()` and check the exitValue to get the final status. If <> 0, then you know an error occurred.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help! I'll do that.